# How can I debug Javascript code along with IOS App code?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode4.2

In my iPhone app I have few JavaScript (.js) files and using JavaScript functions I am loading UIWebview contents.

How can I debug code of JavaScript file while debugging my iPhone App code written in Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Weinre project and see if it meets your needs: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

I have used it in iOS projects with good success. You won't necessarily get breakpoint-style debugging, but you can inspect javascript objects that are logged to the console, look at the document markup (via the webkit dev tools) and more. It has been very helpful.